# Implementing a function in R that computes minus-log-likelihood

Tags: r, statistics

Homework.

I am new to R and statistics. I have a problem where is should implement a user defined function that takes degrees of freedom ("df") and a data set as arguments and returns the minus-log-likelihood.
It is assmued that the data is chi-squared distrbuted with "df" degrees of freedom.

I know the minus-log-likelihood is defined as:

[image: Minus-log-likelihood]

I will only apply this function to the same data set, so my function can have the signature: loglike <- function(df)

Edit: I followed the user shadows advice and tried to write the function:

```
 loglike <- function(df) {
 value <- sum(-log(dchisq(data, df)))
 return(value)
 }
```

Can this be right?

Comment: This looks like homework.  If so, that's not a problem, but best to identify it as such from the get-go.

Comment: You are right. I have however looked through notes and textbook and could not find a correct way to approach it. This is the reason I dared to ask here. I think I have control of the syntax, but the direct implementation is my problem.

Comment: `?dchisq` might get you started.

Comment: Thank you shadow. I have tried to write the function in an edit. I am however unsure if it is correct.

Comment: I am not thinking. My data set has a length of 100 values, so it might not be that off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log likelihood:

```
   minusLogLike <- function(df, data) -sum(dchisq(data, df, log=TRUE))
```

Notice the use of `log=TRUE`. A little example of estimating by MLE follows:

```
dat <- rchisq(100,5)
optim(2, minusLogLike, lower=1, upper=10, method="Brent", data=dat)
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any particular reason you use the "Brent" method? My data is one-dimensional however.

Comment: You are welcome, if this is in fact homework remember to mark it as such in the future. `method="Brent"` because your parameter space (df) is one-dimensional.

Comment: Do you mean I mark it as such in the tags? Also, I get an error when using your MLE code: Error in fn(par, ...): unsused arguments from data file. My data is numeric and [1:100]. Thank you for your help, J.R.

Comment: No just in the top of your question. This should work, make sure your `data=...` actually specifies the numeric vector containing your data. If it still won't work, add the data to your question with `dput()`.

Comment: I will edit that, and remember it for future questions. I still cant get the code to work, not even with the dput() function. It is not mandatory for me to do right now, but I was stil interested in using MLE.

Comment: Use `dput` to add your data to your question in general. Then when asking SO for help, they know how to specify a solution.

Comment: I will do so in the future. Thank you for your help!